# SQL Server BULK INSERT syntax

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I write bulk insert T-SQL query for this flat file

```
7273|80110200|1
8152|58130103|1
10715|87480302|1
20462|76991103|1
21964|72159903|1
25537|59219900|1
30600|58120310|1
```

I want to know how I can define the field terminator and row terminator

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
BULK INSERT test.dbo.bulkinserttest  -- your target table here (db).(schema).(tablename)
FROM 'd:\test.txt'    -- that's the path to your file with the data
WITH
(
    CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR ='|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

This is straight from the wonderful [MSDN Books Online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365.aspx) which you can check for further details.